# How to start bare X server (X -retro &) in Linux OS using Python script?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, xserver

I am a newbie and trying to automate a Linux-based Test in Python. Please help me.

This is what I have tried. But It does not work. No errors but display shows blank black screen.

```py
subprocess.Popen(['pkill', 'X'])
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.Popen(['X', '-retro', '&']).communicate()
subprocess.Popen(['export', 'DISPLAY=:0']).communicate()
subprocess.Popen(['openbox', '--replace', '&']).communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `export` will have no effect as each command is evaluated in an separate shell if a shell is required otherwise only fork and exec will be involved. Pass the environmental variables via the dictionary keyword argument.

Communicate will wait until the program exits. Also `&` is pointless as Popen does not wait for the program to finish and there is no sense in backgrounding a job in what is not a shell and has no concept or status of such distinction.

```
subprocess.Popen(['pkill', 'X'])
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.Popen(['X', '-retro'])
import sys
env = dict(sys.environ)
env['DISPLAY']=':0'
subprocess.Popen(['openbox', '--replace'], env=env)
```

If there is a problem with this it lies with the commands involved and not the Python code.